# How to switch between column mode ieeeconf latex

Tags: overleaf, ieeeconf

I'm writing a paper on Latex using the `ieeeconf.cls` template, and I can't figure out how I can switch from the `twocolumn` mode to `onecolumn` for the appendix.

My `main.tex` looks as follows:

```
\input{sect/01-introduction.tex}
\input{sect/02-analysis.tex}
\input{sect/03-features.tex}
\input{sect/04-more-analysis.tex}
\input{sect/05-conclusion.tex}

\appendix
\input{sect/appendix.tex}
```

And the appendix file looks like this.

```
\newpage % I want to push the appendix to a new page after conclusion
\onecolumn % This kinda works, but leaves one page blank for no reason
\section{Appendix} \label{appendix}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
\includegraphics[width = \columnwidth, height = 5cm]{images/density/density_0.png}
\caption{Digit '0'}
\label{fig:digit_0_density}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\onecolumn` is defined as `\clearpage\global \columnwidth \textwidth \global \hsize \columnwidth \global \linewidth \columnwidth \global \@twocolumnfalse \col@number \@ne \@floatplacement`, so the page break is intentional.

Comment: @Skillmon hi! thank you for your reply, I am aware of that fact, that's why it's an ugly solution for the time being.

Comment: Just leave the `\newpage` out. `\onecolumn` does already move your appendix on the next page.

Comment: @Skillmon You can add this as an answer to the question so I can approve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since `\onecolumn` does issue a `\clearpage` it already starts a new page by itself. You get an additional blank page because you're using `\newpage` before it. If you leave that `\newpage` out, you'll get your appendix starting on a new page in one column mode, just as you want it to. So your file should look like the following:

```
\onecolumn
\section{Appendix}\label{appendix}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
\includegraphics[width = \columnwidth, height = 5cm]{images/density/density_0.png}
\caption{Digit '0'}
\label{fig:digit_0_density}
\end{figure}
```